# Is it possible to draw on the canvas from inside an object function?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, canvas, prototype

I've created an object in JavaScript which holds all data needed for context.drawImage(). Is it then possible to call those values and run context.drawImage() inside an object function?

```
world = new Sprite(0, 0, 100, 100, 0.4, 0, 0, 0);
world.draw();

function Sprite(spriteX, spriteY, spriteW, spriteH, scale, positionX, positionY, direction)
            {
                this.imagePath = world_sprite;
                this.spriteX = spriteX;
                this.spriteY = spriteY;
                this.spriteW = spriteW;
                this.spriteH = spriteH;
                this.scale = scale;
                this.positionX = positionX;
                this.positionY = positionY;
                this.direction = direction;
                this.speed = 5;

                this.noGravity = false;
                this.direction = 0;

                //Physics stuff
                this.velX = 0;
                this.velY = 0;
                this.friction = 0.98;
            };
Sprite.prototype.draw = function()
            {
                context.drawImage(this.imagePath, this.spriteX, this.spriteY, this.spriteW, this.spriteH, this.positionX, this.positionY, this.spriteW * this.scale, this.spriteH * this.scale);
            };
```

Comment: Sure it's possible.  As long as all the properties you're using are defined.  In your short example, I don't see where `context` comes from.

Comment: For `drawImage()` it looks like it takes a loaded image object, not a path.

Comment: this.imagePath refers to world_sprite which is an image object.. I'll see if it doesn't like this.imagePath

Comment: Noo, that wasn't the issue...

Comment: OK, `imagePath` is a bad name for an image object.  You didn't comment on where the `context` variable comes from.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that.. No idea why my objects won't draw though :/

Comment: Maybe it is because scale is 0. Width and height will be 0

Comment: Sorry, I made a bad example there. None of my code has a scale of 0.

Comment: Need more code from you. One thought: Did you use `world_sprite.onload` to give the image time to fully load?

Comment: No, I haven't used that. Where would it be appropriate?

Comment: I've added an answer assuming that you have failed to properly use `onload`. But please show more code because you're leaving us to guess at what's wrong in your undisplayed code.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, of course you can draw on the canvas from inside an object function...**

This code has a problem:

```
var world_sprite=new Image();
world_sprite.src='someImage.png';

// This next line is executed too early!
// The code attempts (fails) to drawImage world_sprite
// because it has not fully loaded yet
world = new Sprite(0, 0, 100, 100, 0.4, 0, 0, 0);
world.draw();
```

The browser always loads images asynchronously. So in the above code, the line after `world_sprite.src='someImage.png'` is always executed before the image is fully loaded.

**You always need to give your `new Image`s time to load by using their `onload` callback**.

```
var world_sprite=new Image();
world_sprite.onload=function(){
    alert('I am displayed when world_sprite is fully loaded and ready to be used in `drawImage`);
};
world_sprite.src='someImage.png';
```

So you would use `onload` in with your code like this:

```
// Create your Sprite "class"
function Sprite(spriteX, spriteY, spriteW, spriteH, scale, positionX, positionY, direction){
    this.imagePath = world_sprite;
    this.spriteX = spriteX;
    this.spriteY = spriteY;
    this.spriteW = spriteW;
    this.spriteH = spriteH;
    this.scale = scale;
    this.positionX = positionX;
    this.positionY = positionY;
    this.direction = direction;
    this.speed = 5;

    this.noGravity = false;
    this.direction = 0;

    //Physics stuff
    this.velX = 0;
    this.velY = 0;
    this.friction = 0.98;
};
Sprite.prototype.draw = function(){
    context.drawImage(this.imagePath, this.spriteX, this.spriteY, this.spriteW, this.spriteH, this.positionX, this.positionY, this.spriteW * this.scale, this.spriteH * this.scale);
};


// create and load world_sprite
var world_sprite=new Image();
world_sprite.onload=function(){
    // Only now is the world_sprite fully loaded and
    // ready to be used in drawImage.
    // So now create a new Sprite and do .draw()
    world = new Sprite(0, 0, 100, 100, 0.4, 0, 0, 0);
    world.draw();
};
world_sprite.src='someImage.png';
```

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed answer. The reason I haven't provided enough code is because my program is 600 lines long... And to show all code linked to the issue, would be quite a lot. So I condensed it down a lot and missed some stuff. Unfortunately, this didn't fix my issue. :/ I'll keep looking further into this. But +1 for the nice answer